# How do I use multiple lines in Kotlins when switch?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, switch-statement

Kotlin uses `when` instead of `switch` and it looks something like this:

```
when(version) {
    "v1" ->
        Log.d("TAG", "WOW")
    "v2" ->
        Log.d("TAG", WOAAH")
    else ->
        "Log.d("TAG", "ELSE")
```

So far so good. But what if I want to add several lines of code after each conditional? This is my code, and I have tried using `and` at the end of each new line:

```
when(version) {
    "anhorig" -> 
        Log.d("TAG", "Anhorig") and
        subHeader.text = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)

    "personal" ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Personal")
    else ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Else")
}
```

I get an error on line

```
subHeader.text = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)
```

saying `Type mismatch. Expected Int, found string and Unit`

The code line works fine if separated from the `when` code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As soon as I put the line `subHeader = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)` outside of the `when` closure, the code works. All code is in `onCreate`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to surround your multiple lines of code in a block, like so:

```
when(version) {
    "anhorig" -> {
        Log.d("TAG", "Anhorig")
        subHeader.text = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)
    }
    "personal" ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Personal")
    else ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Else")
}
```

As for the type mismatch, the value of the when expression is equal to the last evaluated statement within the block. It seems like the expected value of this expression is Int, but your last statement is `subHeader.text = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)` which is string.

You can read more in the Kotlin documentation for [when expressions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression).

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error. I have tried with brackets `"anhorig" -> {
                                    Log.d("TAG", "WHEN Anhorig") and
                                    subHeader = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)
                                }` both with and without the `and`

Comment: @tore: I have updated my answer with an explanation for the type mismatch.

Comment: OK, found the problem. I had put a `Log.d` at a place in the `where` enclosure that apparently wasn't accepted (and that wasn't shown in my example code). Works wonders now. Many thanks for your help @Dehodson :D

Answer (score 1):

When a case of a `when` statement is more than one line, you should use the block of code  in braces `{}`. Like this:

```
when(version) {
    "anhorig" -> {
        Log.d("TAG", "Anhorig")
        subHeader.text = getString(R.string.sv_anhorig_ch1)
    }
    "personal" ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Personal")
    else ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Else")
}
```

And of course you should remove `and`